# Paypal REST API error: Duplicate Transaction and Duplicate Invoice ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

About 2-3 weeks ago I added PayPal payment processing to my site and it worked like a charm with no problems. Now I've come back to the project to tweak the code. I haven't touched the Paypal code that I finished 2-3 weeks ago, and I tried to pay an invoice.

I am currently running this in sandbox. The error I am getting is a duplicate transaction, duplicate invoice id. However each invoice ID is unique to each invoice created so I don't see how that could even be an issue (let alone I didn't touch the code). Below is an image of the error I am getting while using Paypal Connection Exception.

[image: Image of the error:]

So now I'm stuck and completely lost on what I should do to fix this issue. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved. You cannot pass in your own unique invoice ID (idk why), I just used uniqid() and it works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... This doesn't make much sense... Isn't a unique invoice ID no different to a uniqid()? My unique invoice IDs are really unique so I don't understand!

Comment: Yeah it didn't make much sense, but using uniqid() worked for me. Ha sorry that was an old PHP project from a while back, haven't touched it in a while